# Fuzzy matches getting higher scores than Exact matches

Tags: elasticsearch, boto3, elasticsearch-5

I am new to ElasticSearch and was trying to configure Elasticsearch to give me fuzzy matches. On implementing the fuzzy search, autocomplete filter and shingles, the exact matches seem to be having a lower score than partial matches. For instance, if the query is "Ring", it seems to have a higher match with "Brass Ring" instead of "Ring".

Can anyone help me out?

Here is how I make the index:

```
 itemindex = es.indices.create(
        index='mo-items-index-1',
        body={
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "autocomplete_filter": {
                        "type":     "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram": 20
                    },
                    "custom_shingle": {
                        "type": "shingle",
                        "min_shingle_size": 2,
                        "max_shingle_size": 3,
                        "output_unigrams": True

                    },
                    "my_char_filter": {
                        "type": "pattern_replace",
                        "pattern": " ",
                        "replacement": ""
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "type":      "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "custom_shingle",
                            "autocomplete_filter",
                            "my_char_filter"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "item_id": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"

                },
            "item_name": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"

                }
            }
        }
    }
       },
        # Will ignore 400 errors, remove to ensure you're prompted
       ignore=400
    )
```

Here is how I query a term:

```
 res2 = es.search(index="mo-items-index-1", size=200, body={"query": {"multi_match": {
        "fields": [
            "item_name", "item_id"], "query": userQuery, "fuzziness": "AUTO"}}, "highlight": {

        "fields": {
            "item_name": {},
            "item_id": {}

        }
    }, })
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple way to "boost" the score of exact matches: using a `bool` query that will use your already existent query and a `term` one inside `should` statements:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "item_name",
              "item_id"
            ],
            "query": "Ring",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "item_name.keyword": {
              "value": "Ring"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

And you'd have also to add a `keyword` type of subfield to the field that you want to favor a perfect match for:

```
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "item_id": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "item_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I have items like "Pin", "Mickey Pin", "Blue Pin" and "Cap","Baseball Cap","Red Cap" so do I need to add Pin, Cap etc to the "value" field under item_name.keyword?  Something like "value": ["Ring","Pin","Cap"]? Thanks in advance

Comment: Judging by your question, you didn't read the documentation about Elasticsearch. Not even the basics. For a sub-field you don't have to do anything. Elasticsearch will populate the sub-field automatically. If you using the Dev tools in Kibana (which I recommend) you have here a complete test with mappings, data and query: https://gist.github.com/astefan/f3e8f9ff870c5efed860588186af7e14

Comment: Yes, I need to have a look at the documentation. With this config, when I query the term "ring", the top result is  "centering ring" when "ring" exists in the index. Can you tell what could be happening?

Comment: It's all about this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/scoring-theory.html meaning how many documents there are in a shard, what terms they have, what's their frequency, the length of a field containing a certain term etc. Basically, the more documents a shard has the better estimated the score is.

Comment: "With this config, when I query the term "ring", the top result is "centering ring" when "ring" exists in the index. Can you tell what could be happening?" Have you figured out a way to make sure that "ring" comes before "centering ring" ? I am stuck on same problem. Appreciate your help.